# Assign activities to user on assigning lead in SugarCRM

Tags: php, smarty, sugarcrm

I want to assign activities to the user whom lead is assigned.
How can I do this in SugarCRM.
I tried exploring the Connector Settings etc. and searched google a lot, but didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign Sugar Activites to a User when a lead is assigned to that User, you can either call an [After Save Hook](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.2/60_Logic_Hooks/20_Module_Hooks/after_save/) in Leads and grap the assigned user id from the bean or you can work with an [After Relationship Add Hook](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.2/60_Logic_Hooks/20_Module_Hooks/after_relationship_add/) in Users or Leads and check if a Lead was related and grab the assigned user id from there.

In these Hooks you can use the user id to assign new Activites or get the e-mail address from the User Object and send an mail or whatever...